# Weird routing issue - don't see packets on the closest hop

Tags: linux, routing

I have Linux box, which should connect to the remote server via site-to-site VPN (Fortigate):

- **My server**: `10.10.10.10`
- **Fortigate**: `10.10.10.11`
- **Remote server**: `111.111.111.111`

VPN is black-box for me, I have no access to the remote server, but have access to the local Fortigate. I added this route on my Linux:

```
ip route add 111.111.111.111 via 10.10.10.11

ip route get 111.111.111.111 output:
   111.111.111.111 via 10.10.10.11 dev ens5 src 10.10.10.10 uid 0
   cache
```

Now: I don't have connectivity to the remote server, so I decided to check my packets (from `10.10.10.10` to `111.111.111.111`) on the closest hop - local `10.10.10.11` Fortigate. But `diag sniffer packet` doesn't show my packets. I'm not so familiar with Fortigate, so I reproduced this with a plain Linux box instead of Fortigate - I don't see the packages on `10.10.10.11`...

Any ideas?

Comment: Does tcpdump/tshark on the source host show the packets going out via ens5? Do they go to the correct MAC address (in case there are multiple devices with the same 10.10.10.11 address)?

Comment: Good point, thanks! Checked right now - yes, I see these packages in 'ngrep' dump on my 10.10.10.10.

Comment: Is the destination MAC in those packets correct? Are there any switches or bridges between you and the Fortigate? (hopefully not routers?)

Comment: @user1686 - it's AWS, so I have no idea about physical network. But MAC is OK - I can ping between 10.10.10.10 and 10.10.10.11

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that – AWS and other hosting environments may actually be a problem, as they often use more complex setups than just ordinary Ethernet KW (e.g. filtering to prevent address spoofing, or SDNs that only give the illusion of a direct path); it could very well be that the AWS network literally refuses to deliver packets to your Fortigate when they're addressed to a different destination IP (i.e. when you're using it as a gateway), I know it's the case with Linode at least.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS in particular (nor with Fortigate), so there isn't any real answer I could post, but generically I would try to set up a GRE tunnel between the client host and the Fortigate – and route through that.

Comment: @user1686 - many thanks! I'm using AWS for at least 8 years, but I didn't know that by default AWS "elastic network interface" checks source/destination, so ignores "transit" packages.

Comment: _[disregard the 'KW', that was supposed to say 'L2' but somehow got in unnoticed]_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS `elastic network interface` ignores transit packages, because by default Source/dest. check == true.

We should disable this check for routers.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html